# What is the OpenCV font base size for cv::HersheyFonts?

Tags: python, opencv, fonts

From http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext:

> fontScale – Font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific
>   base size.

What is the base size for the hershey fonts? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: base size as in ? Pixels ?

Comment: sure, pixels. unless it's in some other unit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing said in the documentation or anything really readable in the source code.

You can try with using [getTextSize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#Size%20getTextSize(const%20string&%20text,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20int%20thickness,%20int*%20baseLine)) To get the size in pixels of the test string with the font you choose, I think it is not monospaced so it varies which letters you use.

Answer (score 6):

When I use Python [getTextSize](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#Size%20getTextSize(const%20string&%20text,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20int%20thickness,%20int*%20baseLine)), it returned tuple data structure.

For example,

```
textSize = cv2.getTextSize(text=str(act_class_info[0]), fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=1, thickness=1)
print(textSize)  # ((61, 22), 10)
```

It looks like (61, 22) is width of three letters and height of one letter in pixel unit. I don't know what the number 10 is meaning.

Comment: The third returned value is the baseline according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73056754/819417