# how do we interpret the "baseline" output of cv2.getTextSize?

Tags: python, image, opencv

If I do this for example:
`cv2.getTextSize('blahblah', cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)`
it returns `((262, 43), 19)`

so the width and height of the text in pixels are 262 and 43, but what is the 19?

[Here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mastering_OpenCV_4_with_Python/w86PDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cv2.getTextSize&pg=PA123&printsec=frontcover) it says it "corresponds to the y coordinate of the baseline relative to the bottom of the text" but this still doesn't make it clear to me, as I'm not sure what the "baseline" is here?

Comment: If you write text on lined paper, the "baseline" is the line on the paper.  Characters with descenders (g, j, p, q, etc) go below the baseline, but letters like "a" and "o" sit right on the baseline.  You have to know that, because you need to leave room for the descenders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `baseline` here is the yellow line in the figure on page 124. It is the line on which the letters sit. That is according to

> Pay attention to how the three little points (*red*,*cyan*, and *green*) are drawn and **also to how the yellow baseline is shown**.

[image]